# Error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) when performing quality control on genetic data

Tags: perl

I am hoping you may be able to help me with a problematic script I am running as part of some quality control checks on a genetic analyses dataset I am running.

When I run the script, which is a Perl script (run in Windows), I get the following error:

`Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at /IC/ic.pl line 803, <$z> line 1.`

Looking at the `ic.pl` file, line 803 that seems to be generating the error is the following line:

```
if (/^##/)
```

in the following part of the script:

```
my $header = <$z>;
if ($header =~ /^#.*/) {
    my $loop = 1;
    while ($loop) {
        if (/^##/) {  }
        else {
            $header = <$z>;
            $loop = 0;
        }
    }
}
chomp $header;
```

I am not sure what the problem is. If anyone is able to shed some light on potential causes I would be so grateful.

I have tried to run the same script via the Windows Subsystem for Linux/Ubuntu, and I receive the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your error means that the `$_` variable is undefined, it does not contain a value. Typically this would happen because the file handle is exhausted, or was never opened, or the file is empty.

In your case it probably happens because you tried to invent your own loop control, and it does not check for eof (end of file).

Typically, you never run into this problem, because it is idiomatic to use something like this to read a file:

```perl
while (<$fd>) {
    ....
}
```

This construct will not yield any undefined values, since that will end the loop.

If you do want to end the loop before it reaches eof, you can use `last`:

```perl
while (<$fd>) {
    if (! /^##/ ) {
        $header = <$fd>;
        last;              # exit loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to modify the code as you suggested but I got the following error message:  `Global symbol "$fd" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fd"?) at C:\Users\****\Desktop\IC\ic.pl line 801.
Execution of C:\Users\****\Desktop\IC\ic.pl aborted due to compilation errors.`  To clarify, should I have replaced the whole chunk of code with your suggestion above, or just part of it? Thank you.

Comment: Well, `$fd` is the idiomatic variable for a file handle. Your code uses `$z` instead. I'm not sure just copy pasting code will work, as I do not know the context. Can you explain what the code you have posted is doing?

Comment: The code you posted looks somewhat broken, and if the rest of your program is equally broken and 1500 lines long, it might be easier to just write a new program. In short: it reads a line from the file handle (I assume $z is a file handle), it checks if that line begins with #, and if it does, goes into a possibly endless loop which can only be exited if the current line does *not* begin with ##. If the current line is not ## it reads a *new* line from the file and assigns that as $header. Since the loop never progresses naturally, it is either 1 iteration, or infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
if (/^##/) {  }
```

is short for

```perl
if ($_ =~ /^##/) {  }
```

But you don't set `$_`. That line is probably supposed to be

```perl
if ($header =~ /^##/) {  }
```

Full fixed code:

```perl
my $header = <$z>;
if ($header =~ /^#.*/) {
    my $loop = 1;
    while ($loop) {
        if ($header =~ /^##/) {  }
        else {
            $header = <$z>;
            $loop = 0;
        }
    }
}

chomp $header;
```

But there are still some problems with that. I think you meant to place the `$header = <$z>` in the "then" part of the if statement. Fixed (and simplified):

```perl
my $header = <$z>;
$header = <$z> while $header =~ /^##/;

chomp $header;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this by replacing the code with the fixed code you suggested but it didn't work.  When I run the perl script with the changed code included, it runs a serious of continuous errors starting as follows: `Use of uninitialized value $info in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Users\****\Desktop\IC\ic.pl line 1555, <GEN2> line 93575.
Use of uninitialized value $infocol in array element at C:\Users\****\Desktop\IC\ic.pl line 1521, <GEN2> line 93576.`  Is it possible at all for me to share the full script here to see if someone is able to look at it? Thank you.

Comment: Re "*but it didn't work*", There's no variable named `$info` or `$infocol` in my code. This is a different problem. /// Re "*Is it possible at all for me to share the full script here to see if someone is able to look at it?*", If you want to ask a Question about this new problem, you will need distill the problem to its minimum form.